# Kafka : The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests - is it so bad?

Tags: apache-kafka

We did upgrade our Kafka cluster (rolling upgrade to 2.3) few days ago and we notice huge amount of the following ERROR messages with one of our consumer (kafka-console) :

`[2019-09-26 13:02:25,115] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-96306] Offset commit failed on partition TOPICNAME at offset 18834877: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)`

followed by :

`[2019-09-26 13:02:25,115] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-96306] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {TOPICNAME-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18834877, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18825797, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18834407, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18839250, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-8=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18829253, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-9=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18831485, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-10=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18833260, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-11=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18827244, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18835016, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18837478, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18832425, metadata=''}, TOPICNAME-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=18826491, metadata=''}} failed: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets. The underlying error was: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.`

After reading some Kafka code, those errors are due to the fact that the group coordinator was loading some __consumer_offsets segment into memory, and during that time, was not able to request offsets commit requests.

To me, this is not harmful and normal during a broker restart. Should we worry ?
Is there a standard way to handle this situation in our code ?

In the same time we were not even able to do a `./kafka-consumer-group.sh ... --list` ( same error message : coordinator is loading) , so again, anyone can confirm this a complete normal behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

After investigating a while, I still think it's complete normal behavior, but the thing is that we had big consumer offset segments ( due to this behavior : https://medium.com/@ylambrus/youve-got-a-friend-logcleaner-1fac1d7ec04f ). This made the coordinator take more than 10 minutes loading segment offsets.

Besides, old client version don't handle COORDINATOR_LOADING correctly ( and might crash) instead of waiting when the loading takes time.